# Problema al crear formulario con bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, visual-studio-2015, asp

Buenas, he creado una página web utilizando aspx e iis, integrando bootstrap, pero al momento de lanzar el sitio web, se muestra en blanco (imagen 1 y 2) pudiendo de igual manera interactuar con los controles (textbox, de igual forma me permite ingresar al portal) Tengo referenciado el archivo bootstrap desde la página, y también está dentro de la carpeta del proyecto. Esto sucedió de un momento a otro. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

De antemano gracias[![Permite interactuar con textbox][1]][1]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrar como estas insertando las imágenes?

Comment: @claudio hermano puedes mandar pantallaso cuando entras a tu pagina , puede tomar el error que sale en la console para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Tal vez sea un problema de compatibilidad con la nueva versión de Boostrap. En la nueva versión también hay que importar popper.min.js